# How to parse out only top level elements in JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

```
require 'json'

str = ' {
 "body":
[{
  "app_id": 34,
  "properties": [
    "beta",
    "0.0.3b"
  ]
}]
, "code": 200 }'

a = JSON.parse(str)

p a['code'] #200
p a['body'] # [{"app_id"=>34, "properties"=>["beta", "0.0.3b"]}]
```

I need  `a['body']` to contain original JSON content  `[{ "app_id": 34, "properties": [ "beta", "0.0.3b"]}]`

**Update**: I am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? This isn't duplicated in 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Since `a['body']` is parsed JSON and you want the return to be in JSON format, you can do:

```
a['body'].to_json
=> "[{\"app_id\":34,\"properties\":[\"beta\",\"0.0.3b\"]}]"
```

Comment: I need unparsed json as an output for `a[body]`.

Comment: @bioffe so you want `a['body'] => "[{\"app_id\":34,\"properties\":[\"beta\",\"0.0.3b\"]}]"` ?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely what I need.

Comment: @bioffe I updated my answer. I hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I give it to you for trying :) However it's a terrible idea to parse-out and parse-back the same thing twice. Think about what  happens if body is 100mb or larger.

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate the problem you're seeing:

```
require 'json'

str = ' {
 "body":
[{
  "app_id": 34,
  "properties": [
    "beta",
    "0.0.3b"
  ]
}]
, "code": 200 }'

a = JSON.parse(str)
a # => {"body"=>[{"app_id"=>34, "properties"=>["beta", "0.0.3b"]}], "code"=>200}

a['code'] # => 200
a['body'] # => [{"app_id"=>34, "properties"=>["beta", "0.0.3b"]}]
RUBY_VERSION # => "2.2.2"
```

Or rerunning it with 1.9.3:

```
a['code'] # => 200
a['body'] # => [{"app_id"=>34, "properties"=>["beta", "0.0.3b"]}]
RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.3"
```

Comment: I don't have a problem. I am trying to figure out how to parse out only top level elements in JSON

Comment: That makes no sense. You're accessing them. You can't access the original string because, after parsing, it's been converted back into Ruby objects.

Comment: it makes total sense. Imagine 100mb json of which I need only 1 byte and don't want to parse anything deeper nested.

Comment: Then you need to use a JSON SAX-like parser. The built-in JSON loads and parses the entire string.

Comment: Hence the need to search. They exist but asking us to recommend them is off-topic.

Comment: Let's keep this conversation constructive. I did my due diligence and didn't find the answer .

Comment: Perhaps searching for "`ruby json sax parser`"?

Comment: OK.  I need to hear from people who have more experience with custom parsers with standard JSON module, I serendipitously expect more elegant solution than the one you suggested.

Comment: I could encode json as string or process the stream with my own code. I want to learn something. This question does not an easy answer.